# Triggers on SAS SQL

Tags: sql, triggers, sas, proc

I am trying to find on the web how to create a trigger on a SAS table such as MS SQL server triggers, but i cannot find anything at all.

Does SAS support triggers for tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS does not support triggers, unless you're wanting to perform some kind of simple [integrity constraint](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001396785.htm).